# How to get available filters list in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: dynamic, filter, predicate, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm doing a work that dynamically setting routes into the Spring Cloud Gateway in runtime, by using following codes,

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("inMemoryRouteDefinitionRepository")
private RouteDefinitionWriter routeDefinitionWriter;


RouteDefinition routeDefinition = ...; // my own route
routeDefinitionWriter.save(Mono.just(routeDefinition)).subscribe();
this.publisher.publishEvent(new RefreshRoutesEvent(this));
```

The route can be successfully added, no matter if the predicates and filters inside are available or even exist. And exception would occur if there is a route with non-existen predicates or filters.

The question is that how to get available predicates and filters list in runtime, so I can check if the passed-in RouteDefinition is valid.

So far, I've found that the available predicates and filters list inside RouteDefinitionRouteLocator class, and I can autowire an instance of it. But it seems not a good solution to fix the question.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("routeDefinitionRouteLocator")
private RouteDefinitionRouteLocator routeDefinitionRouteLocator;
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just autowired Predicates and Filters as list.

```java
@Autowired
private List<GatewayFilterFactory> gatewayFilters;

@Autowired
private List<RoutePredicateFactory> routePredicates;
```